# TSC TSPL TSPL2 Printer Programming

Tags: printing, tsc, printer-control-language, barcode-printing

I'm wondering if there's a function, or at least the best way, to print on a 3 labels (column) per row paper such as this:

[image]

I'm asking because on the provided label design software (that came with the printer) I can input column count (along with paper & label size), and everything will print correctly.

While on TSPL's docs, I can't find anything on setup functions to input column count or paper size. Only **label size** which must be set up to cover the whole 3 column or it'll only print on the center label.

What I have in mind is to manually adjust the position before each output, placing them on the correct columns. I'm wondering if this is the best approach or not.

Thanks!

Comment: No answer, so I assume it needs to be done manually. Quite simple in my case because everything needs to be centered on each label, so I just have to find the center coordinates for each label, and use them on each text & barcode output. If someone needs help on this unpopular subject (just got a "tumbleweed badge"), don't hesitate to comment.

Comment: pls can you share your code, i have the same issue, did you use this in any advance programming environment like c#

Comment: Hi, when I created this thread I use PHP. Then some requirements change that the "feature" needs to be put into an Android app. No troubles, libraries for both are available (I don't remember C# though) and the command are almost identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution for such label printers is to use a .PRN (raw printer output) and modify it accordingly.

For a 3 labels per row, the easy solution would be to have all the elements replicated in the PRN 3 times and change the X coordinates for each element. Obviously, all the vertical commands (feed, gap, home) would remain the same as for a single label.

This solution works for any environment that supports copying a file to the printer.

Answer (score -1):

For later reference, if you need a WYSIWYG label editor for TSC printers look for **TSC Standalone Creator** and ignore Bartender Designer.

TSC Standalone Creator: is a barebone simple designer and can directly output labels to TSPL2.